# Replace authenticated user agent login/ page scrape using Perl and Mojolicious

Tags: perl, authentication, user-agent, mojolicious

I am trying to port some old web scraping scripts written using older Perl modules to work using only Mojolicious.

Have written a few basic scripts with Mojo but am puzzled on an authenticated login which uses a secure login site and how this should be handled with a [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) script. Unfortunately the only example I can see in the documentation is for basic authentication without forms.

The Perl script I am trying to convert to work with Mojo:UserAgent is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP;
use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::Debug qw(+);
use LWP::Protocol::https;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;

# login first before navigating to pages
# Create our automated browser and set up to handle cookies
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$agent->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$agent->agent_alias( 'Windows IE 6' );  #tell the website who we are (old!)

# get login page

$agent->get("https://reg.mysite.com")
$agent->success or die $agent->response->status_line;

# complete the user name and password form
$agent->form_number (1);
$agent->field (username => "user1");
$agent->field (password => "pass1");
$agent->click();

#try to get member's only content page from main site on basis we are now "logged in" 
$agent->get("http://www.mysite.com/memberpagesonly1");
$agent->success or die $agent->response->status_line;

$member_page = $agent->content();
print "$member_page\n";
```

So the above works fine. How to convert to do the same job in Mojolicious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mojolicious is a web application framework. While `Mojo::UserAgent` works well as a low-level HTTP user agent, and provides facilities that are unavailble from `LWP` (in particular native support for asynchronous requests and IPV6) neither are as convenient to use as as `WWW::Mechanize` for web scraping.

`WWW::Mechanize` subclasses `LWP::UserAgent` to interface with the internet, and uses `HTML::Form` to process the forms it finds. `Mojo::UserAgent` has no facility for processing HTML forms, and so building the corresponding HTTP requests is not at all straighforward. Information such as the HTTP method used (`GET` or `POST`) the names of the form fields, and the insertion of default values for hidden fields are all done automatically by `HTML::Form` and are left to the programmer if you restrict yourself to `Mojo::UserAgent`.

It seems to me that even trying to use `Mojo::UserAgent` in combination with `HTML::Form` is poblematic, as the former requires a `Mojo::Transaction::HTTP` object to represent the submission of a filled-in form, whereas the latter generates `HTTP::Request` objects for use with `LWP`.

In short, unless you are willing to largely rewrite `WWW::Mechanize`, I think there is no way to reimplement your software using `Mojolicious` modules.

Comment: That's a shame, I find the actual finding and parsing of data much more straightforward with Mojo::UserAgent than WWW::Mechanize and friends.  Do you know how I can easily pass the retrieved pages to Mojo::UserAgent, so that I can use Mojo as the parser?

Comment: you can use Mojo::DOM to extract the form, find all the "name"s and "value"s and the "action" that the click would invoke. Yeah its not quite the same, but still not that hard.

Comment: Yes, you could use `my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($mech->content)`. I don't know how  good the Mojo parser is (i.e. how well it copes with real-world HTML) but if you're willing to split the work between `WWW::Mechanize` and a separate parser then there are many to choose from. `HTML::DOM` for instance, or my favourite `HTML::TreeBuilder`

Comment: Having used HTML::TreeBuilder etc. I find Mojo::Dom to be much easier to use (supports CSS selectors for example), more succinct in terms of code, and faster.  What's not to like?!  Of course TIMTOWTDI, it's Perl and all that, but for folk visiting this thread who are new to parsing HTML, Mojo::DOM may be the easiest place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WWW::Mechanize` to talk to web servers, and you can use [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) to benefit from Mojolicious' as a parser. The best of two worlds... :)